# [[BoxSDK sharedSDK].foldersManager createFolderWithRequestBuilder:builder success:success failure:failure] not working

Tags: ios, directory, box-api

I am having trouble creating a folder in box.com  Here is my code.  I am having trouble with foldersManager createFolderWithRequestBuilder  If I breakpoint on the return I get "op = POST https://api.box.com/2.0/folders"

```
- (void)boxAPIAuthenticationDidSucceed:(NSNotification *)notification
{
NSLog(@"Received OAuth2 successfully authenticated notification");
BoxOAuth2Session *session = (BoxOAuth2Session *) [notification object];
NSLog(@"Access token  (%@) expires at %@", session.accessToken, session.accessTokenExpiration);
NSLog(@"Refresh token (%@)", session.refreshToken);

dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
});

BoxFolderBlock success = ^(BoxFolder *folder)
{
    [self fetchFolderItemsWithFolderID:self.folderID name:self.navigationItem.title];
};

BoxAPIJSONFailureBlock failure = ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, NSDictionary *JSONDictionary)
{
    NSLog(@"folder create failed with error code: %i", response.statusCode);
    if (response.statusCode == 409)
    {
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIAlertView *conflictAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Name conflict" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"A folder already exists with the name %@.\n\nNew name:", @"ezMedRecords"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

            conflictAlert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;

            [conflictAlert show];
        });
    }
};

BoxFoldersRequestBuilder *builder = [[BoxFoldersRequestBuilder alloc] init];
builder.name = @"ezMedRecords";
builder.parentID = self.folderID;

BoxAPIJSONOperation *op;

op = [[BoxSDK sharedSDK].foldersManager createFolderWithRequestBuilder:builder success:success failure:failure];

return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is self.folderID?
It should be a valid folderID of the folder that exists on Box.
To save to "all files", start with builder.parentID = @"0";

BTW, what is error message that you get in your failure block?
Does failure block execute at all?
I'm talking about this line:
NSLog(@"folder create failed with error code: %i", response.statusCode);

Comment: I changed to builder.parentIDD = @"0";  Got the same result.  Nether success nor failure blocks execute.